# How can I get the value of the url(s) that don't validate in this function that uses YQL?

Tags: jquery, yql

This example validates urls correctly. How can I identify which one(s) didn't validate? I want to trigger a single alert in the `else` section or get the value(s) to perhaps use elsewhere.

```
function check_URL() {

var url = "http://" + localStorage['t'] + ".tumblr.com";
var url1 = "http://" + localStorage['t1'] + ".tumblr.com";
var url2 = "http://" + localStorage['t2'] + ".tumblr.com";
var url3 = "http://" + localStorage['t3'] + ".tumblr.com";

var urlArray = ['url', 'url1', 'url2','url3'];
$(urlArray).each(function (urlItem) {
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
            encodeURIComponent(urlItem)+
            "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data){
      if(data.results[0]){
        console.log("yes");
      } 
      else { 
      console.log("no");

      alert("? is not a valid URL or is down.");

     }
    }
  );
});
};
```

Thanks from the newbie for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through an array you need to use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Also, you don't need to wrap the variable names in a string. Doing so will just return `"url"` rather than the value of the variable.

```
function check_URL() {

  var url = "http://" + localStorage['t'] + ".tumblr.com";
  var url1 = "http://" + localStorage['t1'] + ".tumblr.com";
  var url2 = "http://" + localStorage['t2'] + ".tumblr.com";
  var url3 = "http://" + localStorage['t3'] + ".tumblr.com";

  var urlArray = [url, url1, url2, url3],
      invalidUrls = [];

  $.each(urlArray, function (i, urlItem) {
    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
    "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
    encodeURIComponent(urlItem)+
    "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data){
      if(data.results[0]){
        console.log("yes");
      } 
      else { 
        invalidUrls.push(urlItem);
      }
    }
    );
  });

  return invalidUrls;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly on first test. "Teach a man to fish …" Learning more every day. So, you declare an empty array 'invalidUrls' and store the 'urlItem' value(s) there with the 'push' ? Guess I could make "http://" and ".tumblr.com" vars (H + DOMAIN) too for something like 'var url = H + localStorage['t'] + DOMAIN' But, not sure if it adds any value to the function. Again, thanks!

Comment: @user1452893 here's some more information about `.push()`. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp - The reason for using the empty array is for when all the urls are valid your code won't break because it expected an array and got something else.

Comment: Great, thanks! Trying to sort out the alert now. Odd in Safari where it is repeating with valid urls. Chrome displays correctly but one for each invalid url.

Comment: Safari is showing the valid urls rather than the invalid. Yikes!